# Solving for $t, -{\sqrt3}\sin t+\cos t-4\sin 2t=0$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$-{\sqrt3}\sin t+\cos t-4\sin 2t=0,$$
>   with $-\frac\pi 2\lt t\lt \frac \pi2$.

Hey guys, I've been trying to solve this for some time now.
Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: \begin{align*}-\sqrt{3}\sin(t)+\cos(t)&=-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}\sin(t)+\cos(t) \\ &=\frac{\cos(t)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\sin(t)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=2\cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped me.